# Подскажите, кто знаток Linux

Tags: linux, ftp-сервер

После закачки на сервер фалов по ftp, права и владелец на файлы, папки - меняются. Владелец становиться root, а атрибуты - только чтение. Можно ли сделать, чтобы при закачке файлов, владелец становился admin, права на папки были 0755, а на файлы 0644 ?

Comment: Можно. Но как конкретно это делается зависит от используемого ftp-сервера.

Comment: То есть  надо именно ftp настраивать ? А не Linux

Comment: Да, вам надо непосредственно сам ftp-демон настраивать. Сделайте `ps aux | grep ftp`. Это поможет выяснить, какой сервер вы используете.

Comment: @zoonman, Он может и не иметь в названии ftp, поэтому правильнее запускать *netstat -nap -t*.